# Do not display #VALUE! if no calculation occurs

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My Excel sheet has a comment column "O".  If the comment in "O" contains an email address, column "Q" will pull it with this:

`=IF(O7="","",TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(O7,FIND(" ",O7&" ",FIND("@",O7))-1)," ",REPT(" ",LEN(O7))),LEN(O7))))`

If column "O" does not contain any information, the `=IF(O7="","",FORMULA` section will leave column "Q" blank.  However, if column "O" contains information, but does not contain an email address, I get the filled-in error of `#VALUE!`.  I need this field to be blank if the formula does not capture an email address, as it will cause issues with the script that uses this document.

Does anyone know how to make column "Q" display nothing if it does not successfully calculate based on its formula?  I need column "Q" to display nothing if the formula in column "Q" does not resolve any information.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Have you tried `IFERROR()` function to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Felix said, try IFERROR:

```
=IFERROR(
    IF(O7="","",TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(O7,FIND(" ",O7&" ",FIND("@",O7))-1)," ",REPT(" ",LEN(O7))),LEN(O7)))),
    ""
)
```

The first argument is the value you try to compute. If an error occurs, the second argument will be the result instead.

Comment: Brilliant!  I was just telling another guy, "There HAS to be an IfError statement for this!"  Thanks so much!